# Alternative of groupby in Pyspark to improve performance of Pyspark code

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My Pyspark data frame looks like this. I have to remove group by function from pyspark code to increase the performance of the code. I have to perform operations on 100k data.

[Initial Data]

To create Dataframe

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
(0, ['-9.53', '-9.35', '0.18']),
(1, ['-7.77', '-7.61', '0.16']),
(2, ['-5.80', '-5.71', '0.10']),
(0, ['1', '2', '3']),
(1, ['4', '5', '6']),
(2, ['8', '98', '32'])
 ], ["id", "Array"])
```

And the expected output is produced using this code.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df.groupBy('id').agg(f.collect_list(f.col("Array")).alias('Array')).\
select("id",f.flatten("Array")).show()
```

I have to achieve the output in this format. The above code is giving me this output. I have to achieve the same by removing the groupby function.

```
+---+-------------------------------+
|id |flatten(Array)                 |
+---+-------------------------------+
|0  |[-9.53, -9.35, 0.18, 1, 2, 3]  |
|1  |[-7.77, -7.61, 0.16, 4, 5, 6]  |
|2  |[-5.80, -5.71, 0.10, 8, 98, 32]|
+---+-------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to do group by, you can use window functions:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df2 = df.select(
    "id",
    f.flatten(f.collect_list(f.col("Array")).over(Window.partitionBy("id"))).alias("Array")
).distinct()

df2.show(truncate=False)
+---+-------------------------------+
|id |Array                          |
+---+-------------------------------+
|0  |[-9.53, -9.35, 0.18, 1, 2, 3]  |
|1  |[-7.77, -7.61, 0.16, 4, 5, 6]  |
|2  |[-5.80, -5.71, 0.10, 8, 98, 32]|
+---+-------------------------------+
```

You can also try

```
df.select(
    'id', 
    f.explode('Array').alias('Array')
).groupBy('id').agg(f.collect_list('Array').alias('Array'))
```

Although I'm not sure if it'll be faster.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The solution provided by you is taking the same time (approx 3 minutes) as it was performing the operation using my code. I was looking for a solution which does the operation in at least 1 minute time.